# Is it a good habit to write TODO to commit message?

Tags: git, todo, commit-message

I just realized that I prefer writing TODO notes directly in to the latest commit instead of issue tracker, for example:

```
TODO:
- Remove console.log
- Check that XY works
- ...
```

For example if I have to switch to another job, finishing it and coming back to this branch I can see what had I left undone, fixing it, `commit --amend`, removing the TODO statements from the commit message.

Is this a good habit or should I force myself to use the issue tracker and write every little notes there (even if others can see the issue)?

Comment: You should look into [worktrees](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree)

Comment: If it does not affect your colleagues (you don't push it etc.), it's only for you to evaluate convenience of this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd say it is sub-optimal.

Consider this: if a TODO refers to **code** it should be next to that piece of code. If you write it in a commit message, it becomes completely detached. How is your fellow programmer to identify where to look when she wants to implement the TODO?

If a TODO refers not to code, but to infrastructure, documentation, etc., it is much better to maintain a `TODO` **file** because it is much easier to

- find the list of active TODOs
- move an item to DONE (e.g. simply delete it)

Imagine you want a list of TODO items. In your approach, can you grep all commit messages? How do you know which TODOs are DONE? A separate file makes this answer super easy.

Comment: Writing TODO as a comments seems to be good idea (just noticed that my IDE has a dedicated "TODO finder" panel).

Comment: Just did a git alias to find TODOs added to current branch: `git --no-pager diff --color-words --no-color --diff-filter='AM' master | grep TODO | git grep -f - -F 2> /dev/null`

Answer (score 0):

going back and invoking `commit --amend` is rather thought for casual fixes, not for regular workflow.

If you `push`ed your branch already then you will invalidate commits seen by others.

In the situation when issue tracker is an overkill - I can totally understand that - just keep separate TODO file in whatever form, plain text of markdown for example, then add its changes to your code commits.

Comment: If I adding the TODO to the commit, then I should delete the completed items from it ->`commit --amend` the changes. I don't see the differences between storing the notes in a file and in the commit message.
**EDIT:** Ok, misunderstood your answer. So you saying that I should commit every little prettifying in different commits. Well, I don't like this, but it's another question (to squash or not to squash).

Comment: @bimlas Note that modifiying/amending commit messages is a big no-no in many environments, and rightly so. History in general is unchangeable,.

Comment: "History in general is unchangeable": then what's the purpose of `rebase.autoSquash` in Git config - I think there are a lot of people prefer clean log over keeping every commit.

Comment: @bimlas not sure about 'commit every little prettifying' approach - this seems to be your own idea. I usually do lot of code commits and edit one line on TODO file once some functionality is done, after a merge or similar. So it's avg one change in notes for a dozen of commits. Not much overhead. YMMV